# What does L and IL mean in the crash dump string?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, crash-dumps

While going through a crash dump, I encountered following line

```
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
```

I have few quesions which I eagerly want to understand.

What does IL and L stand for in the string `ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;`

What is V+35 at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are type strings in a method signature.

```
(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V
```

The `I` means `int`

The `Ljava/awt/Conditional;` means `java.awt.Conditional`

The `Ljava/awt/EventFilter;` means `java.awt.EventFilter`

The `V` means `void`.

So the method on the callstack is

```
  void pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter)
```

This internal type string syntax is documented in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) for `Class.getName()` and also in the JVM specification.  (The same syntax appears in the strings generated by `Object.toString` ... assuming that it hasn't been overridden with something more human friendly.)

And the `+35` is a bytecode offset; i.e. an indication of *where* the method execution had gotten to in this stackframe.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle's documentation on the [fatal error log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/fatal-error-log.htm#JSTGD542) is quite shallow when it comes to answering your questions.

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29174273/13755503) at least has a thorough explanation for the `+35` bit in your crash dump. According to that answer this is giving you the offset in the generated byte code.

`IL` and `L` still remain a mystery.